# how to upload / store any file in mysql database from php page

Tags: php, mysqli

So after HOURS of fruitless searching just about anywhere I could find, I'm asking for help. 
I have a simple html form that asks for some input, and lets me select a file just fine, then sends it to a php form that is supposed to connect to my MySQL (finding nemo moment there for a second...) and save the file into a longBLOB.
Tried reading from my /tmp directory. nada
Tried reading straight from `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` and nada.
Tried the code below and just about every mix and match of code I could read, glean, or shamelessly plagiarize from the interwebs and still nada.

```
$sendUp = $_POST["whatDoc"];
$teamCriteria = $_POST["team"];
$lastNameCriteria = $_POST["lastName"];
$firstNameCriteria = $_POST["firstName"];

$myFile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fn = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$fl = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fp = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($myFile));
$content = addslashes($content);

#lines below changed for obvious reasons
$con = mysqli_connect("the usual", "the usual", "*********", "the usual");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "UPDATE leo SET '$sendUp'=$content WHERE Last='$lastNameCriteria'";

mysqli_query($con, $query)or die('Error, query failed');
```

at wits end here, could REALLY use a lifeline.

Thanks all.

ps. like I said, done a LOT of reading tonight, I know that there are better and more efficient ways to store files than to upload pics / pdf / everythingunderthesun as a BLOB in a database but that's what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: `file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])` is that what you read?

Comment: you missing move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],"../images/" . strtolower($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));

Comment: Try encoding the read data using base64_encode() and then store them into a LONGBLOG field.

Comment: Why not to try **a regular approach first**, and then, after you get it work - start with some unusual ideas you have?

Comment: @DevZer0 Yeah, that's one of the approaches I tried. @ Rakesh Concatenating together a name and then using the file move function to store the file in the server local file system doesn't solve my question, or help me in the least. @ Alejandro I tried that one too at some point yesterday, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You have used single quotes around table name, but that should be backticks `` ` ``.

```
$query = "UPDATE leo SET '$sendUp'=$content WHERE Last='$lastNameCriteria'";
```

should be

```
$query = "UPDATE leo SET `$sendUp` = '$content' WHERE Last='$lastNameCriteria'";
```

Comment: I suspect that there should also _be_ quotes around `$content`, although parameterising the query would be better since it's `mysqli` anyway. The dynamic field name makes this approach break if someone decides to try SQL injection though.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Weird thing is in a different form using INSERT statement, regular quotes instead of backticks worked just fine. Thank you though, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Wish I could upvote so more people could see this. That worked like a charm, I simply replaced the first set of single quotes with backticks and added single quotes around the variable `'$content'`

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not store files in database. Store them in a filesystem instead.
2. Your database structure is wrong for this purpose anyway. There shouldn't be dynamical field names.
3. With approach you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Too bad I can't downvote. 1. Like I said, I understand that I shouldn't but I still want to. 2.Dynamical? 3. I understand I'd be wide open, this wasn't about SQL injection, if it were I would have asked about proper string sanitation using methods like `MySQL_real_escape_string()` Thanks for weighing in though.